# Wie übersetzt man "the [noun] of not [verb]-ing"?

Tags: translation

Examples:

> the advantage of not requiring the installation of a video distributor
>   the cost of not having a constitution
>   the risk of not undergoing formal vocational training
>   the importance of not taking short cuts
>   the pain of not being with you

Wie übersetzt man diese Konstruktion?

Die naheliegende Übersetzung "der/die/das [Nomen], [Nomen] nicht zu [Infinitiv]" erscheint mir unelegant und holprig. Wie geht's schöner?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t get what you mean with “requiring the installation”, but here are the other sentences translated:

> Der Preis, keine Verfassung zu haben
>
> Das Risiko, keine Berufsausbildung zu machen
>
> Die Wichtigkeit, keine Abkürzungen zu nehmen
>
> Der Schmerz, nicht mit dir zu sein

You either need to use *keine* and *zu + verb* or *nicht* and *zu + sein.*

Comment: Zwei Menschen, ein Gedanke... ;-) Aber bitte das Komma vor dem erweiterten Infinitiv nicht vergessen.

Comment: ...besser(?): *nicht bei dir zu sein*

Comment: Wie wäre es mit "die Kosten davon, ... [ etw zu tun ]" oder "die Kosten dessen, ... [ etw zu tun ]"? Sind diese Formen falsch?

Answer (score 1):

Mit *Substantiv, "keine" (oder andere Negation) und Infinitiv mit zu.*

Deine Beispiele:

> ...der Vorteil, keinen Videoverteiler einrichten zu müssen
>   ...die Kosten, keine Verfassung zu haben
>   ...das Risiko, keine Berufsausbildung zu machen
>   ... und so weiter

(Nicht besonders schön übersetzt, aber das Muster sollte so erkennbar sein.)

Comment: Danke. Das: "Nicht besonders schön übersetzt" ist aber genau der Punkt. Mir scheint, diese Konstruktion im Deutschen einigermaßen unschön. Ich denke, hier wäre eine freie Übersetzung nötig.

Comment: Das kannst Du, je nach Zielgruppe, natürlich gerne machen, eine Übersetzung im wörtlichen Sinn ist es dann mE aber nicht mehr.

Comment: @Ingmar Außerhalb des Sprachunterrichts sind wörtliche Übersetzungen in der Regel unpassend. Z.B. "Der Preis für das Fehlen einer Verfassung." oder "... was den Vorteil mit sich bringt, dass wir keinen Videoverteiler einrichten müssen."

Comment: Ich sagte nicht "wörtliche Übersetzung", ich sagte Übersetzung im wörtlichen, dh eigentlichen Sinn. Je nachdem kann man dann nämlich durchaus bereits von Nachdichtung sprechen. Wie auch immer, das alles hängt nur von der Zielgruppe ab.

Comment: Naja, wenn die Fragestellung ein Muster beschreibt, dann wird die Antwort auch genau das Muster wiedergeben (wenn sprachlich möglich). Ob das besonders schön ist, sei dahingestellt. Natürlich sind "elegantere" Übersetzungen für die *einzelnen* Sätze möglich, aber als "Strickmuster" werden kaum andere Antworten kommen, allenfalls Varianten zu den bisherigen Vorschlägen.